# Why do LineBreaks not work in wxpython RichTextCtrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working on a moderately complicated text editing program using wxpython and I encountered an odd problem. I can not insert line breaks on the last line of a paragraph.

Below is a minimal working example code in python3 wxPython 4.1.0 that lets you insert line breaks in some paragraphs.

Notice that even the line break in paragraph 2 which is in the code does not show up in the GUI.
And if you go to the last line and press Shift+Enter which normally inserts a line break, it does not work. It works on the second line and first line but not on the last line.
The same problem occurs inside the first link. But strangely you can insert a line break in the second link.

I suspect I am doing something wrong with the styles but I can not find out what.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt


class RichTextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, style=wx.VSCROLL | wx.HSCROLL | wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.rtc, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self._stylesheet = rt.RichTextStyleSheet()
        self._stylesheet.SetName('Stylesheet')
        self._create_styles()
        self._insert_sample_text()

    def _create_styles(self) -> None:
        """
        Create styles for rich text control.
        :return: None
        """
        # Normal style
        stl_paragraph: rt.RichTextAttr = self.rtc.GetDefaultStyleEx()
        stl_paragraph.SetParagraphSpacingBefore(10)
        stl_paragraph.SetParagraphSpacingAfter(10)
        style_paragraph: rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition = rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition('par')
        style_paragraph.SetStyle(stl_paragraph)
        style_paragraph.SetNextStyle('par')
        self._stylesheet.AddParagraphStyle(style_paragraph)
        self.rtc.ApplyStyle(style_paragraph)
        self.rtc.SetDefaultStyle(stl_paragraph)

        # Link style
        stl_link = rt.RichTextAttr()
        stl_link.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_URL)
        stl_link.SetFontUnderlined(True)
        stl_link.SetTextColour(wx.BLUE)
        style_link: rt.RichTextCharacterStyleDefinition = rt.RichTextCharacterStyleDefinition('url')
        style_link.SetStyle(stl_link)
        self._stylesheet.AddCharacterStyle(style_link)

    def _insert_link(self, text: str, link_id: str) -> None:
        """
        Insert a link into text at current position.
        :param text: The visible text.
        :param link_id: The ID of the link
        :return: None
        """
        self.rtc.BeginStyle(self._stylesheet.FindCharacterStyle('url').GetStyle())
        self.rtc.BeginURL(link_id)
        self.rtc.WriteText(text)
        self.rtc.EndURL()
        self.rtc.EndStyle()

    def _insert_sample_text(self) -> None:
        """
        Insert sample text.
        :return: None
        """
        self.rtc.ApplyStyle(self._stylesheet.FindParagraphStyle('par'))
        self.rtc.BeginParagraphStyle('par')
        self.rtc.WriteText('paragraph 1, sample of a longer text for testing url creation ')
        self.rtc.LineBreak()
        self.rtc.WriteText('paragraph 1, more sample of a longer text for testing url creation ')
        self._insert_link('www.google.com', 'link from code')
        self.rtc.EndParagraphStyle()

        self.rtc.Newline()

        self.rtc.ApplyStyle(self._stylesheet.FindParagraphStyle('par'))
        self.rtc.BeginParagraphStyle('par')
        self._insert_link('www.google.com', '42')
        self.rtc.WriteText(' paragraph 2 adding some text after a link')
        self.rtc.LineBreak()
        self.rtc.WriteText(' some more text after a line break in code')
        self.rtc.EndParagraphStyle()

        self.rtc.Newline()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    """
    Main class for running the gui
    """

    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.frame = None

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = RichTextFrame(None, -1, "RichTextCtrl", size=(900, 500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: do you have to use wxRTC? Can you use wxTextCtrl or wxSTC?

Comment: Thanks. On top of ordinary text I also need to be able to insert urls, headings (which is basically text but bigger), colored text and images. When I was looking for something that can do images richtextctrl popped out. I am not sure whether ordinary textctrl can do that plus I need to be able to process left or right click on the images and urls.
The stc seems more capable. But I have not used it at all. Do you think it will be better at handling paragraphs and line breaks?

Comment: I found out that the LineBreak() probably does not do what I though it does. 

"Inserts a line break at the current insertion point.
A line break forces wrapping within a paragraph, and can be introduced by using this function, by appending the Char value RichTextLineBreakChar to text content, or by typing Shift-Return."

What I need is a plain ordinary new line in the same paragraph. Just like what happens when you press Shift+Enter right here in this comment box.

Comment: wxTextCtrl does support URLs. I'm not sure about the images though. You can try with the text control with wxTE_RICH2 style. Such text control also support coloring. Just look at the text sample. But like I said - I'm not sure if you can insert and process image. Try to modify the sample and see what happens.